# Need help writing test case for below .subscribe in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

```
            ngOnInit{
            .subscribe( (name: Name) => { 
            if(!name){ 
                this.close 
            } else { 
                this.name = Name 
            } 
            })
            }
```

I need help writing test cases so that it covers this.name=Name in code coverage. Thanks.

Comment: Try to learn code formatting.  It helps people to understand your code.

Comment: sorry I am new to Stackoverflow, the code is formatted now.

Comment: Unit test is usually done on a function. I don't know much about angular or typescript, but I guess you need to learn about testing in general. A good YouTube tutorial, along with documentation of testing library in the language of your interest should help. All the best.

Comment: i think we are not on the same page here, what do you mean by "writing test" ?

Comment: I need to write a test case so that it gets covered in coverage.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test the function handling new events you could extract it:

```
const onNewName = (name: Name) => {
  if(!name) {
    this.close();
  } else {
    this.name = name;
  }
};

<observable>.subscribe(onNewName);
```

Then you should be able to test it fairly isolated without mocking the observable.
You still reference `this` in your function so you have to setup the component properly for testing.

Comment: I have updated the code. What if it is in ngOnInit?